# Java or Django for Liferay?

Tags: java, django, liferay

I would like to get an opinion what language is better to use with LifeRay. I would like to build some app that I would like to integrate with LifeRay. What language do you suggest would I learn first?

Java? - A friend suggested that Java and LifeRay goes well.

Django? - I recently new this and seen the overview I find this pretty straight forward and I think would be easy for me to learn But I don't know if fits with LifeRay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liferay is written in 100% Java.

I don't know if there even exist a portlet in Python/Django. There is a Ruby/Rails bridge for Liferay Portlets http://rails-portlet.rubyforge.org/ , but I would definitely go for Java.

(Liferay) Portlets are based on Java Standards (JSR-268, JSR-186) so Java is the way to go.

Comment: yes Java would be the best for LifeRay. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Others have already answered that Liferay is a Java application. Let me add that there are definitely numerous ways to utilize other languages to customize liferay.

However, as you ask about what language to learn first be warned that a portal container is not the easiest environment to learn and - in addition to the language - you'll have to learn a great deal about the specifications implemented, the coding style and other used frameworks.

In code size, Liferay is huge. If you start to learn one of the two languages there are two aspects:

- Regarding Liferay, support in the forums on [www.liferay.com](http://www.liferay.com) is best in Java, I've rarely seen support for other languages (neither questions nor answers)
- Regarding your personal learning curve: If you're working closely together with django folks you might get better support for them in django.

Basically: You have to decide for yourself. Learning a new language *and* a new framework/server/environment is tough.

Comment: Yeah, I Think would really have to learn JAVA for LifeRay. Thanks for the Tip!

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to write JSR compliant portlets in Ruby, PHP and Groovy as well as Java through [Portal Pack](http://www.liferay.com/web/satyaranjan/blog/-/blogs/1257304) - you could also run Django through Jython on the app server backing LifeRay and use this to back portlets.  I'm not sure how preferable this would be to just doing it in Java though...

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, Jython would also be great solution.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thought Liferay was a Java-based portal product.  If Django and Python are an option, I'm not aware of it.

[This link](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/4b8d3fdc39afe9cd) suggests that I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay does support creating portlets in scripting languages.

[Take a look at their wiki for help](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Scripting+languages+to+develop+portlets++)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Liferay DXP with many languages: Java, Kotlin, Scala. Liferay also works with web frameworks like JSF, Lexicon, Groovy, GWT, JQuery, Twitter Bootstrap, Metal.js, React.JS, Angular JS and Angular 2, Node.js, Ruby and special mention Vaadin. Personally I´ve experience in Vaadin and Angular 2.
What I mean is that Liferay (just as develop portal, ant take out any content manager functionality) it is an excellent front integration for different developer teams, you can unified in a single security, look&feel, notification portal (and for the end-user it is seamless).

Django was developed with other objectives like reusability and pluggability, which it does an excellent work. But I don´t see any many Django portals.

So if you are looking to develop a portal using "micro-front" (term for web pages as micro-server is for back systems) using OSGi standard for many different system, go for Liferay. Django is more for monolitic systems.